# How to integrate Dialogflow API v2 with MS BotFramework using dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-functions, dialogflow-es

I am building a bot using MS BotFramework functions and I am trying to use Dialogflow with MS BotFramework but I am failing with setting up configuration. dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2 library requires that **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** environment variable is set. Which I believe I set :

[image]

I've also manually uploaded conf file into the, what I believe is the working directory

[image]

Yet bot is still failing. I tried various paths as value of a variable including absolute path : `D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\test-0691d01dae88.json`

still with no luck.

Error I am getting is very cryptic :

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: package.json does not exist at D:\home\site\wwwroot\package.json
at Object.module.exports.exports.find (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:272715:15)
at Object.module.exports.exports.status.OK (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:51739:12)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:21:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:271412:12)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:21:30)
at Object.module.exports.module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:84837:27)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:21:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:260961:14)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:21:30)
at new GrpcClient (D:\home\site\wwwroot\.funcpack\index.js:132359:25).
```

It suggest package.json is missing but this error only occurs if I try to use dialog flow to be specific I require recognizer.js file in index.js.

```
var apiairecognizer_v2 = require('./recognizer');
```

It's content is :

```
"use strict";
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow').v2beta1;
const uuid = require('uuid');
// next line causes error 
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

var ApiAiRecognizer = function(){
};

ApiAiRecognizer.prototype.recognize = function (context, done){
}

module.exports = ApiAiRecognizer;
```

Commenting out sessionClient line will make bot work.

Any idea how to configure Dialogflow v2 with MS BotFramework functions?

thanks

Comment: Try adding package.json file using Kudu. Kudu can be accessed by using the below url. https://functionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole Then you can find the path and manually upload package.json file.

Comment: That's not a problem. It works fine if dialogflow is not used

Answer (score 1):

Error seems straight forward for any node.js application. You are using statement:

```
var apiairecognizer_v2 = require('./recognizer');
```

So application is expecting package.json file for installing packages like:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "devDependencies": {
     "dialogflow":"^0.6.0",
     "uuid":"^3.3.2",
     "recognizer":"^0.0.2"
  }
}
```

it is used for installing package by npm.

Error is that it is expecting **package.json** with **all referenced & dependent packages** there in location `D:\home\site\wwwroot\package.json`

You can either manually add that or try going to that folder if node is installed & npm is used, try

```
npm install --save recognizer
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev recognizer
```

it will save latest package in package.json.

It seems you are already getting two packages `dialogflow` & `uuid` resolved using npm without error so issue is missing `recognizer` entry in package.json.
Try adding package in package.json there.

Comment: It's not a problem as package.json is present in messages folder which is root of the app. Other dependencies works just fine. Issue is that Google cloud services needs configuration file and this do not work

Comment: Error suggests Google cloud services or your component using that is not able to find package.json for installing required package. Somewhere setting relating npm to package.json is missing. It is by default same folder where app is running until changed.

Comment: GCS is looking for a file specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable. package.json error is very misleading as skeleton of the app is generated and whole project works fine GCS is not used. You can reproduce problem locally but with different error if credential files is missing.